# Is there a way to fetch list of files belonging to a particular file format from a folder in a zip in Artifactory using REST/AQL?

Tags: artifactory, artifact, artifactory-query-lang

We have a use case to download or at least list all .xml files from a folder inside a zip in Artifactory from a python script. Is it possible with REST or using AQL ? I am looking for a search query to get all xmls from a folder in zip so that I can use "archive entries download" thing from REST API to make download request for each file individually. Please help me with relevant information about the endpoint or query that I can use to achieve my task(list all xml in a folder in zip). Also please let me know of any other efficient approach to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an AQL query to get a list of files from a given path inside an archive.

As an example, lets take the `my-archive.zip` archive deployed in a repository names `myrepo` inside `folder1` folder

[image]

The follow AQL query can be used to find all the xml files within this archive under the path `level-1/level-2/level-3`:

```
archive.entries.find( {
    "archive.item.path":{"$eq":"folder1"},
    "archive.item.name":{"$eq":"my-archive.zip"},
    "archive.entry.path":{"$eq":"level-1/level-2/level-3"},
    "archive.entry.name":{"$match":"*.xml"}
})
```

You can run this query using the [AQL REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)) method and get the following result:

```
{
"results" : [ {
  "entry.name" : "dummy.xml",
  "entry.path" : "level-1/level-2/level-3"
} ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 1,
  "total" : 1
}
}
```

Here is an example of calling this REST API using curl (the query itself is stored in a file called aql.json):

```
curl -XPOST -uadmin:password -H"content-type: text/plain" -d@aql.json http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dror, but I have multiple artifacts with same name in different folders, how to specify the exact archive ? for eg., I have xxxxxx/archive_01.zip and yyyyy/archive_01.zip. I need to query only xmls only from xxxxx/archive_01.zip but not inside yyyyy. Please help @Dror Bereznitsky

Comment: @AnuragAravala you can also filter by the item path. I updated the AQL example in the answer

Comment: Thank you @Dror Bereznitsky, but I don't know why it is giving empty results. At first I will fetch list of all archive.zip using items.find() and sort them with "modified" field. For the above query, I'm using the name and path from the results obtained from items.find(). So i think two arguments for the above query should be correct. the fourth one archive.entry.name should also be correct as you have given the correct matching criteria. I'm giving correct path inside the archive for the third argument and also I have tried it in different ways as well.

Comment: After giving all the four values correctly, I'm not able to find why I'm getting results as an empty list. I have manually checked the zip and there are more than 8000 xmls in that particular location. Can you please help me where I could be wrong ?

Comment: Archive entries metadata is collected by the Artifactory archive indexing capability. In newer version of Artifactory archive indexing is disabled by default. Please check ${ARTIFACTORY_HOME}/etc/mimetypes.xml to see if archive indexing is enabled for zip archives. For more info see https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Configuration+Descriptors#ArtifactoryConfigurationDescriptors-ContentType/MIMEType

Comment: @AnuragAravala are you able to see the zip entries in the Artifactory UI? if not, it is a good indication that they are not indexed

Comment: I'm able to see them clearly inside Artifactory. I'm also able to download archive entry using "archive entries download" thing from REST API by specifying exact location and name of a text file inside the zip

Comment: @AnuragAravala In this case I would say its probably related to the query you are running. Try removing some of the filters (for example the item name and path) to see if you are getting results

Comment: b'\n{\n"results" : [  ],\n"range" : {\n  "start_pos" : 0,\n  "end_pos" : 0,\n  "total" : 0\n}\n}\n'      This is the only response I'm getting even after trying different filter combinations. I'm using items.find() to look for all archive_01.zip. It is working properly and giving all the results, but when I'm trying to get xmls from that particular archive I'm not able to do it.

Comment: the zip is Archive_01.zip and when unzipped, it gives a folder named "archive" inside archive folder, the xmls are in folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4. I wanted to confirm the archive.entry.path , Can u pls help me with the xml path from the above example so that I can cross chek it. the archives are present in folder4 in the above example

Comment: @AnuragAravala the archive.entry.path should be archive/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4 . The archive.item.name should be Archive_01.zip and archive.item.path should be the archive path inside the repository

Comment: Then I'm giving correct values only, I'm not able to figure out the exact problem. Those archives are actually build artifacts, they are stored in a hierarchical folder structure lyk project/version/jenkins_build_target/build_number/archive_o1.zip. Does this info give you any other idea to accomplish the task?

Comment: @AnuragAravala Another thing that might impact query results is permissions. Some queries will require to use a user with an admin role. Try to run the query with an admin user to see if it has impact

Comment: The status code of the http response is 200 but not 401 or 403. Do you still think it's a problem with the access ?

Comment: @AnuragAravala It might be because it is a matter of permissions for viewing some of the results

Comment: An admin user from our org checked all that you have mentioned in the conversation and also tried running the same query but even she's getting empty results. We(me and an admin user) both also tried to run a query from AQL home page(archive.entries.find just as mentioned in the overview) with proper values of archive name, build name and number (these are obtained from properties tab of the archive) and again we are getting empty results. Can you help us with any other thing to look into ?. The query cannot go wrong as it is given in the starting of AQL website itself

Comment: @AnuragAravala I updated the answer with more details.
If you can update the question with the query you are using and other details about the repo/folder/archive I might be able to help more

Comment: Thank you Dror, but I have used the query exactly as you have mentioned, but I'm using python requests instead of curl from command line. Even the values are exactly in the way that you have mentioned but I'm not getting the results. Even the builds.find( ) is returning empty results. It seems like only items.find( ) is working properly with our server. Do you think there is another config option that we are missing to look into ? Our artifactory version is 7.9.0 rev.... something like this, displayed at bottom left in homepage

Comment: I am getting the same result when I try to list all the files answering to a certain format. 
Everything works right, but when I add archive.item.path, I’m getting an empty list, when I remove it, I’m getting a lot of results but it’s the results of all of the folders inside the main zip.